# Slow transfer from internal disk to external USB hard disk

Tags: usb, hard-drive, ntfs, ext4, transfer

Lots of people have problem with copying to/from external USB hard disk. 
My system Ubuntu 14.04. External USB Seagate disk 1T originally NTFS. 
The disk is empty I am trying to copy 100GB to 1T disk. (10%).

Here is my attempt for solution that did not work, but maybe help people to know what does not work.  NTFS: It started with 100MB/sec, then it slow to 3Mbyte/sec. 
I thought that maybe Linux does not like NTFS.I formatted the NTFS to Ext4. Ext4: It started 50MB/sec, it is now slow to 1Mbyte/sec. It seems that neither NTFS or Ext4 work.
Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen 10Mbyte/sec for cp on a 50G file to an external USB3 ext4 (after starting out at 107Mbyte/sec from a SATA internal disk), so your figures are just a little worse.  Looks like a buffering problem.  tar does allow selecting a block factor (increase its buffer) with the -b switch, and while -b 200000 didn't help, -b 2000000 did get the rate up to 30Mbyte/sec.

---

Try using nocache from the nocache package.  This keeps the system buffers from filling up and dragging the system to a crawl.  Results of a large file copy were in the 50MB/sec range.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly same problem using the same operating system+USB drive. The driver provided by Seagate solved the problem:
[Nytro-driver](http://www.seagate.com/gb/en/support/downloads/item/nytro-driver-ubuntu-14-20.00.00.00-master-dl)